# Vue.js on click user from user list, display content from $.ajax() request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, vue.js

I have a user list that is dynamically called with PHP and when i click, an $.ajax() request is triggered and in another div, the content from $.ajax() is loaded. The $.ajax() request is working but I can't use v-model for data binding(because it's a div) and the content with v-for appears empty.

What am I missing here?

users list HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div id="users" name="users">
                   <!--- section to display the list of users starts -->
                        <?php   if(!empty($user))
                        { 
                            foreach($user as $value) 
                            { 
                            ?>
                                <div class="row oddEven usersElements userid" id=<?php echo $value->id;?> style="margin-top: -1vw;">
                                    <div v-on:click="displayAgregators(<?php echo $value->id;?>)" class="col-md-10">
                                        <span id="items<?php echo $value->id;?>"><?php echo ucfirst($value->username);?></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="colorsByUser" :style="{backgroundColor: randomColor(<?php echo $value->id;?>)}"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php } 
                        }?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

HTML code where it's supposed to display the $.ajax() content:

```
<div class="row" id="toprow">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div id="titlerow">User's Aggregators</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input class="searchbar" id="search" placeholder="Search..."></input>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div v-for="agr1 in agr1" id="agregators">{ agr1.id }</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the $.ajax() function:

```
displayAgregators:function(userid) {
  var self = this;
  console.log(userid);
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('userid',userid);
    $.ajax({
      url: url + "/displayAgregators",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
      id: userid
    },
  dataType: "json",
    success:function(response){
      console.log(response);//
      this.agr1=response;
      console.log(this.agr1);
    },
    error:function(){

    }
    });//end $.ajax() request
  }//end displayAgregators function
```

Comment: What is `v="agr1 in agr1"` supposed to be?

Comment: sorry about that. it's a v-for! already corrected the code

Comment: because its {{ }} to output data not { }

Comment: the code it's like this because i added the following code: `delimiters:['{', '}'], ` even with {{ }} it was not working.